# get bean definitions in order they are defined

Tags: java, spring

Can I access bean definitions in order they are declared?

For example there is following xml bean definitions:

```
<bean id="bean1" ... />
<bean id="bean2" ... />
<bean id="bean3" ... />
```

I need somehow access `BeanDefinition` or each of these beans in the order they are declared in xml file.

Comment: what you want to achieve with the order of beans definition?

Comment: @Braj, I need to access overridden beans. Some bean with same `id` is declared later in context and it hides previously declared bean. That is the bean I need to access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any `XML` parser to get definition of all the beans in order.

Simply use [Element#getElementsByTagName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) to get the elements with a given tag name, **in document order**.

Sample code: (printing class names of bean using [dom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) in order)

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class SpringXMLParser {

    public static void parse(String file) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(file));
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("bean");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(((Node) nodeList.item(i))
                                        .getAttributes().getNamedItem("class"));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There could be complex structure of xml files (these files are seared by some 3rd party logic), so it is not an option to scan them manually.

Comment: why would I? Spring context is combined of multiple xml files which are collected by some code that can not be reused. I would need then to duplicate it. That is not an option to parse xmls manually because of these difficulties.

Comment: I always post an answer after testing at my end. I have tested it. I you want then use it otherwise leave it as it is.

Comment: I do not want to say that your solution does not work. It just say that there will be too much work that does not relate to my problem if I use your solution.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any other solution. Keep it as last resort.